# How to ORDER BY in SQL PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I currently have this query using PIVOT generating a table like this:

```
  USER  |  DEC  |  NOV  |  OCT
---------------------------------
  bob   |   3   |   5   |   2
  jon   |   7   |   0   |   1 
  tim   |   4   |   2   |   6
```

What I would like to do but it looks like a stretch is to `ORDER BY` the results by the `DEC` value descending.

This is the query:

```
with Mth (st, nd) as ( 
  select DATEADD (M, datediff (m, 0,'2012-09-01'), 0), 
         DATEADD (M, DATEDIFF (m, 0, '2012-09-01') + 1, 0)   
  union all 
  select DATEADD (m, 1, st), 
         DATEADD (m, 1, nd) 
  from Mth 
  where nd <= DATEADD (m, datediff (m, 0, getdate()), 0)
) 
select * 
from 
( 
  select MONTH(Mth.st) Month, 
      U.USER, 
      COUNT(S.QRY_ID) Searches 
  FROM Mth 
  LEFT JOIN SEARCHES S 
    on Mth.st <= S.CREATED 
    and Mth.nd > S.CREATED 
  LEFT JOIN MEMBERS U 
    on U.AID = S.AID 
  GROUP BY YEAR(Mth.st), MONTH(Mth.st), U.HOLDER_LOGIN
) src 
pivot 
( 
  sum(searches) 
  for month in ([12],[11],[10]) 
) piv
```

Doing `piv ORDER BY piv.Searches` gives an error so is it possible to specify the column?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
with Mth (st, nd) as ( 
  select DATEADD (M, datediff (m, 0,'2012-09-01'), 0), 
         DATEADD (M, DATEDIFF (m, 0, '2012-09-01') + 1, 0)   
  union all 
  select DATEADD (m, 1, st), 
         DATEADD (m, 1, nd) 
  from Mth 
  where nd <= DATEADD (m, datediff (m, 0, getdate()), 0)
), Pivoted
AS
(     
    select * 
    from 
    ( 
      select MONTH(Mth.st) Month, 
          U.USER, 
          COUNT(S.QRY_ID) Searches 
      FROM Mth 
      LEFT JOIN SEARCHES S 
        on Mth.st <= S.CREATED 
        and Mth.nd > S.CREATED 
      LEFT JOIN MEMBERS U 
        on U.AID = S.AID 
      GROUP BY YEAR(Mth.st), MONTH(Mth.st), U.HOLDER_LOGIN
    ) src 
    pivot 
    ( 
      sum(searches) 
      for month in ([12],[11],[10]) 
    ) piv
)
SELECT * 
FROM Pivoted
ORDER BY Dec
```

Comment: @greener - Sorry, it is `DEC`, or any other column you want to order by.

Comment: This is an EXCELLENT solution to sorting the output from pivot operations. As I understand it, it is not possible otherwise.

Comment: A sentence or two to explain what you are doing and why it works would be very very useful. I figured it out, but a few words would have helped. I had to do 'spot the difference' on the two pieces of code !

Comment: Really would have useful to add some commentary