# The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries

Tags: sql-server

my stored procedeur like this:

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[ParkingDeatailsReportnewstack] 
      @startdate NVARCHAR(100),
      @enddate NVARCHAR(100)AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE  @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX) , @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @cols = STUFF((  SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(Vtype)
    FROM dbo.VType_tbl FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

    SET @query =
        'SELECT  LocName,Date, ' + @cols + '
         from  ( 
                select  l.LocName,v.Vtype, convert(date, dtime) as Date 
                from Transaction_tbl t 
                join VType_tbl v on t.vtid = v.vtid 
                join dbo.Location_tbl l on t.locid=l.Locid
                where dtime between ''' + @startdate + ''' and ''' + @enddate + '''  order by l.LocName
         ) d
         pivot (
                count(Vtype) for Vtype in (' + @cols + ')
         ) p '  

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @query
End
```

i want to get my locname in ascending order but while giving
order by l.LocName getting error :The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries

Comment: Have you tried moving the `ORDER BY LocName` after your pivot?  So after the `) p `?

Comment: For what it's worth, stored procedures don't require `BEGIN` and `END` statements.

Comment: i try to move order by after p that time i am getting error like this"The multi-part identifier "l.LocName" could not be bound

Comment: @user2648161 Don't use the alias, just use `LocName`

Comment: And please fix the spelling of your proc name or the people doing maintenance will curse your name forever.

Comment: Another issue for you: you might want to consider how you're constructing your SQL. That sort of dynamic SQL leaves you open to SQL injection attacks. Whether that's a potential issue for you, only you know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ORDER BY in SQL PIVOT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755017/how-to-order-by-in-sql-pivot)

Comment: If you don't know how to move an ORDER BY clause from a subquery to the outer query properly, I doubt very much you know what you are doing with this query at all. This is not to intimidate you, I just think you may be trying to learn too many things at a time. Consider taking on easier problems, so that you can understand better what you are doing, and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try migrating your `order by` clause into the *outermost* select statement — the only place where `order by` makes any sense.

Something like

```
select LocName ,
       ...
from ...
order by LocName
```

Or, even simpler, wrap the original, complex `select` in an outer select whose sole purpose is ordering, along these lines:

```
select *
from ( select
       ...   
     ) t
order by t.x, t.y , ...
```

Comment: see my amended answer.

Answer (score 3):

We can fix the problem very easily by adding a **TOP 100 PERCENT** clause into the view definition. 
Try using this way -
 http://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2015/05/25/the-ambiguity-of-the-order-by-in-sql-server/

Comment: Better solution when you can't extract your order by to an outer query. Thanks!