# How to get order by

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

In the below Pivot table am not able to get order by Date.Kindly help me.

Ex:-  Nov,Dec,Jan

```
select * 
from
(
    select 
        Dsgn_Entered_By, 
        COUNT(ddif_number) DDIF_Number,
        SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH,Entered_Date),0,10) as Date,
        DATEPART(mm,Entered_Date) Entered_Date
    from Design_Entry_Fixture_Input 
    group by Entered_Date,Dsgn_Entered_By
)
yy
PIVOT
(
    SUM(DDIF_Number) 
    for Dsgn_Entered_By IN ([chandru.r],[praveen.n],[CHETAN B],[HANUMANTH REDDY],[PRAVEEN NAIK],[saravana.k],[Yogitha])
)PVT  
order by Entered_Date
```

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755017/how-to-order-by-in-sql-pivot) may help you

Comment: You are presumably getting an error message. It would be extremely useful if you added the exact text of the error to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * 
from
(
select * 
from
(
    select 
        Dsgn_Entered_By, 
        COUNT(ddif_number) DDIF_Number,
        SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH,Entered_Date),0,10) as Date,
        DATEPART(mm,Entered_Date) Entered_Date
    from Design_Entry_Fixture_Input 
    group by Entered_Date,Dsgn_Entered_By
)
yy
PIVOT
(
    SUM(DDIF_Number) 
    for Dsgn_Entered_By IN ([chandru.r],[praveen.n],[CHETAN B],[HANUMANTH REDDY],[PRAVEEN NAIK],[saravana.k],[Yogitha])
)PVT ) t 
order by Entered_Date
```